# Select value in a row of a data.frame by position (given by column) and replace it

Tags: r, apply, radix

i have a numeric data.frame (Se). Each row is a list of values, for example in row 1, values appear from Column 1:37.
in row 2, values appear from column 1:22, row 3 from 1:26, folled by NAs, totalling in 93 columns.

```
  Plot Point Pen V1 V2 V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27
1    1     1   1 42 42 82 146 331 335 307 315 323 320 320 265 265 263 279 279 279 269 463 463 463 463 488 495 507 461 461
2    1     1   2 50 50 50 143 265 356 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 378 463  65  41  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3    1     1   3 39 39 39  39  68 132 238 346 346 346 346 307 307 307 345 452 491 494 494 494 396 396 551  NA  NA  NA  NA
  V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39 V40 V41 V42 V43 V44 V45 V46 V47 V48 V49 V50 V51 V52 V53 V54 V55 V56 V57
1 380 380 455 455 455 398 515  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
  V58 V59 V60 V61 V62 V63 V64 V65 V66 V67 V68 V69 V70 V71 V72 V73 V74 V75 V76 V77 V78 V79 V80 V81 V82 V83 V84 Von Bis
1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 255   1   1  14  13
2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 255   1   1  14  13
3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 255   1   1  14  13
       Top fiveteen twentyfive NoFirstNA
1 3.567619 3.145000   4.553000        38
2 2.845333 2.718889        NaN        23
3 3.608421 4.037000   4.476667        27
```

I used an apply function, to estimate the column number, where the first NA appeared.

```
#I added the y-position of the first value of NA (NoFirstNA) like this
NAD <- function(x) {min(as.data.frame(which(is.na(x) == TRUE, arr.ind = T)))}
NoFirstNA<-apply(Se, 1, FUN = NAD)
Sept<-data.frame(Se, NoFirstNA)

#this would work for one row, but i need it for the data.frame

Sept[1,Sept[1,]$NoFirstNA-1]  <- NA
Sept[1,Sept[1,]$NoFirstNA-2]  <- NA
```

Now I want do delete the last two values in each row (e.g. row 1, V33 = 398 and V34 = 515) or replace them by NA.

The solution should erase the last two values from each row, as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would do a similar approach to identify a vector containing the first `NA` in each row:

```
NAindex <- apply(Se, 1, function(x) which(is.na(x))[1])

R> NAindex
[1] 38 23 27
```

Then identify row and column to replace with `NA`. In this case there are 3 rows (1, 2, and 3), and column numbers would be based on `NAindex-1` and `NAindex-2`.

```
Se[cbind(1:nrow(Se), c(NAindex-1, NAindex-2))] <- NA

R> Se
  Plot Point Pen V1 V2 V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
1    1     1   1 42 42 82 146 331 335 307 315 323 320 320 265 265 263 279 279 279 269 463 463 463
2    1     1   2 50 50 50 143 265 356 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 378 463  NA  NA  NA  NA
3    1     1   3 39 39 39  39  68 132 238 346 346 346 346 307 307 307 345 452 491 494 494 494 396
  V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39 V40 V41 V42 V43 V44 V45
1 463 488 495 507 461 461 380 380 455 455 455  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
...
```